# Scala inheritance with recursion

Tags: scala

I am going through some example scala code and couldnt figure out the outcome of the code.

I tried adding prints in the code to understand the code flow

```
abstract class MyList {

  /*
  1. head -> returns the first element
  2. tail -> returns the remaining elements
  3. isEmpty -> is the list empty
  4. add(int) -> new list with this element added
  5. toString -> a string representation of this list

   */

  def head: Int
  def tail: MyList
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def add(element: Int): MyList
  def printElements: String
  override def toString: String = "[" + printElements + "]"

}

object Empty extends MyList {
  def head: Int = throw new NoSuchElementException
  def tail: MyList = throw new NoSuchElementException
  def isEmpty: Boolean = true
  def add(element: Int): MyList = new Cons(element, this)
  def printElements: String = ""

}

class Cons(val h: Int, val t: MyList) extends MyList {
  def head: Int = h
  def tail: MyList = t
  def isEmpty: Boolean = true
  def add(element: Int): MyList =  new Cons(element, this)
  def printElements: String = {

    if(t.isEmpty) {
      println("hi")
      "" + h
    }
    else {
      println(h)
      h + " " + t.printElements
    }
  }
}

object ListTest extends App {
  val my_list = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(3, Empty)))

  println(my_list.toString)

}
```

My expected output is:
1
2
3
[1 2 3]

But the actual output is:
hi
[1]

This seems the recursion is not working. Please help me understand it.

Comment: `def isEmpty: Boolean = true` in **Cons** is wrong, it should be `false`.

Comment: [@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez] Thanks a lot. Completely missed that.